# Add/Remove fields from About Yourself section of Wordpress Author Profile

Tags: wordpress

I have found numerous tutorials accross the web regarding how to add and remove fields from the 'contact info' section of the author profile page in the admin utilizing some code in the fuctions.php file. However, I cannot find anything regarding how to do the same in the 'about yourself' section of the author profile page. I specifically want to create an 'extended bio' text area to appear right below the standard 'biographical info' text area.

could someone point me in the right direction?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_action("edit_user_profile", "my_form_fields_func")` to place form fields below the bio textarea.  Use `add_action("edit_user_profile_update", "my_form_capture_func")` to capture the form data.  If you need to validate and add errors use the action hook `user_profile_update_errors`.